# only border row and outside table bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to remove the border vertical of the table except outside as shown below with bootstrap

[image]

I tried

```
 <table class="table no-footer worker-data table-bordered"....
.table td, .table th {
      border: none;
}
```

But result

[image]

Comment: try with `.table th { border: none; }`, leaving style for `.table td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the below approach.

- Clear the right border for first child of row.
- Clear the left border for last child.
- Clear right and left border for all other other child ec=xcept the first and last child of row.

**Working Example**

```css
.table td:first-child, .table th:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.table td:last-child, .table th:last-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.table td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child),
.table th:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table no-footer worker-data table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```